# Adding onclick function to input labels within riotjs element

Tags: javascript, riot.js

Starting with this working element, sans-js: http://jsfiddle.net/37z1z7g1/

```
<star-rating></star-rating>
<script type="riot/tag">
  <star-rating>
    <div class="star-rating">
      <input class="rb0" id="Ans_1" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" />
      <input class="rb1" id="Ans_2" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="1" />
      <input class="rb2" id="Ans_3" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="2" />
      <input class="rb3" id="Ans_4" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="3" />
      <input class="rb4" id="Ans_5" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="4" />
      <input class="rb5" id="Ans_6" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="5" />
      <input class="rb6" id="Ans_7" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="6" />
      <input class="rb7" id="Ans_8" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="7" />
      <input class="rb8" id="Ans_9" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="8" />
      <input class="rb9" id="Ans_10" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="9" />
      <input class="rb10" id="Ans_11" name="numericRating" type="radio" value="10" />
      <label for="Ans_1" class="star rb0l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_2" class="star rb1l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_3" class="star rb2l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_4" class="star rb3l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_5" class="star rb4l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_6" class="star rb5l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_7" class="star rb6l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_8" class="star rb7l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_9" class="star rb8l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_10" class="star rb9l"></label>
      <label for="Ans_11" class="star rb10l last"></label>
      <div class="rating"></div>
      <div class="rating-bg"></div>
    </div>
  </star-rating>
</script>
```

Notice that if you click one of the stars, it holds that ‘value’ of number of stars selected (click star 4 and the first 4 stars will remain selected after it loses mouse focus).

This is what I end up with when I add some js logic to be run when a star is clicked (having replaced the call to a parent function with console.log for the purposes of JSFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/0u5oLyp5/

```
    function update(e) {
      this.score = parseInt(e.target.value)/2;
      if (this.score) {
        //parent.UpdateScore(this.score);
          console.log(this.score);
      }
        return true;
    }
```

[along with

```
onclick="{ update }"
```

added to each label element]

I have two issues here:

1) Note that I have put the word function in front of the “update(e)” declaration, contrary to all of the examples in the guide on https://muut.com/riotjs, because if I don't do this then I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘target’ of undefined
```

as it seems to be running the function on page load while ‘e’ is not yet defined instead of just declaring the function. I found this odd but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

2) Even though I have “return true” at the end of my update function (to re-enable the default events), clicking the stars does no longer hold the selection as highlighted in blue when it loses mouse focus. As soon as I remove “onclick='{ update }'” from each label element, the selection works again so it definitely appears to be an issue with me not successfully triggering the default event handler.

Is anyone able to offer some pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem was that I had named the function "update" which is also the name of the internal update function inherent in all Riot elements.

update is normally run during the mount process hence the error in point 1 of my query, as I had overwritten the default update function by when run during mounting there is no event being passed in. Therefore no 'target' of undefined. This means I did not need "function()" before the declaration once I changed the function name from "update()" to "StarsChanged".

This then fixed the issues I was having with the selection not remaining in place (in query 2) as well. Go me.